# Using ArrayFormula with Query or Filter

Tags: arrays, filter, google-sheets-formula, flatten, google-query-language

I have a set of data and I want to filter it on some conditions.

My data goes here(image1):

[image]

Similarly, I have another column that has a unique value of A column and it goes like this (image 2):

[image]

Now my problem is I am trying to filter my data(image 1) with the name matching in image 2 with one additional condition.

My filter formula works fine but only for the first name in image 2.

I am trying to get output for all the names mentioned in image2 using the Array formula. Here is my formula :

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(Filter(data!$A2:C,Data!$A2:A='Sheet1'!H2:H,Data!$B2:B="MATCH"))
```

Comment: Arrayformula does not work with query or filter formulas. When used it returns only first value.

Comment: can you give me a work around if possible?

Comment: Please share sample data and I will work on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY({A2:A, B2:B, C2:C}, 
 "select max(Col3)
  where Col2 = 'MATCH'
  group by Col3 
  pivot Col1"),,9^9)), " "))
```

[image]